# Get datepicker value to prepopulate a field after redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a form with a datepicker field and I want when I submit this form to redirect me to another page and pre-populate an input-field in another form.

To be more specific.

I have the form with the jquery datepicker field:

```
<form id="form" action="form.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="datepicker-field" id="datepicker"/>
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value="check"/>
</form>
```

And the form.php page has another form

```
<form id="another-form" action="mail.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="input-field" id="input-field"/>
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value="check"/>
</form>
```

I suppose I have to initialise the datepicker value somehow But I haven't got any javascript knowledge.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I would suggest doing it from the server side rather than the client side

Comment: Any suggestion how? Thanks for the quick response

Comment: you have the value posted at server, set it in second datepicker when you generate the  markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
<form id="another-form" action="mail.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="input-field" id="input-field" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['datepicker-field']) ?>"/>
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value="check"/>
</form>
```